# What I should improve in my code to migrate data from csv file to database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV file with the following layout:

[image]

In my code below, what can I improve if i want to get data without null cell and name table at the begin?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "C:\\Users\\\\Desktop\\project\\x.csv";
        File file = new File(path);

        Connection connect = null;
        Statement s = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            try {
                Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                connect =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://johnny.heliohost.org:5432/hostdb_allotments" +
                        "?user=hostdb_administrator&password=");

                s = connect.createStatement();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            try {
                                String[] arr = line.split(",");
                String sql = "INSERT INTO Dzialki " +
                                            "(Nr_dzialki, Powierzchnia) " + 
                                            "VALUES ('" + arr[0] + "','" + arr[1] + "') ";
                s.execute(sql);
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                 System.out.println("Import success!");
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

}
```

Comment: If you don't want to insert null values then check the values and ignore the nulls. You'll probably want to only do that if all values of a row are null. To ignore the column names you first have to know which line they are in. In your case it seems to be line/row one so skip that when reading the file.

Comment: not good wway in other spreadsheat i have 3 cells which i wont migrate. In this is 2 cells. so

Comment: So - what's the problem? Ignore any cells/columns/rows that you don't want to import. We can't tell you what to do because it's _you_ who knows the data and the requirements.

Comment: Btw, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), so unless you absolutely know where that data comes from and trust the source bad things could be made to happen (like dropping your database, deleting all your data etc.).

Comment: if i remove != null in while i have abug

Comment: "if i remove != null in while" - did anyone suggest that? If you misunderstood  "ignore the nulls" then let me rephrase: check the values in a line and if all are null then skip that line and check the next (i.e. if all elements in `arr` are null or empty strings don't execute the sql).

Comment: i don't know how do it. Many bugs

Comment: Well, for a start you could have a look at Johan's answer. He admits it's not perfect ("adding a null check would solve it _for now_") but it should get you started. As I said expanding that to other cases (e.g. with 3 or more columns) is something _you_ have to do, since we don't know your requirements, skills, constraints etc. ... and SO is _not_ a code writing site.

Comment: his solution is bad. While break from loop

Comment: Actually his solution is yours, just with an added check for `arr[0] != null && arr[1] != null`, which is what I was talking about as well. He admits it's not perfect but it should get _you_ started. Again note that we can't and _won't_ provide full solutions. It's your task and your job, we're here to help not do all the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Reading file contents straight into an sql statement seems like a bad idea to me. But adding a null check would solve it for now:

```
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
          try {
            String[] arr = line.split(",");
            if(arr[0] != null && arr[1] != null) {
               String sql = "INSERT INTO Dzialki " +
                         "(Nr_dzialki, Powierzchnia) " + 
                         "VALUES ('" + arr[0] + "','" + arr[1] + "') ";
               s.execute(sql);
            }
          } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          System.out.println("Import success!");
        }
```